# Change kotlin val in debugger

Tags: android-studio, debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin

How change `val` **property** (not method variable) in **debugger**?

Yes, I know that `val` is final analog

Breakpoint here:

[image: Code with breakpoint]

`Set value` disabled in context menu:

[image: Context menu]

Evaluate not work:

[image: Evaluate window]

Comment: Then  you should know you can't change a final, assigned value unless you somehow [hack something together with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection). It's final for a reason

Answer (score 7):

In the debugger select the value use the context menue on right click to select "set Value..." (default shortcut <kbd>F2</kbd>). The value of the variable should now be displayed in a text field. Enter the desired value and press enter to change the value. You only need to enter the value not an assignment (e.g. `x = "test"` is wrong, just enter the value `"test"`). The changed value is now applied to the field.

In the debugger it IS also possible to change values on immutable `val` defined values in Kotlin as it is also possible to change the value on `final` defined variables in Java.

Comment: thanks, but this not work with `val` property. I update question

Comment: No it is not possible for val

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using reflection.
Just open the Evaluate Expression menu, then type:
`val field = Main::class.java.getDeclaredField("b")`
`field.isAccessible = true`
`field.set(b, true)`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to modify `val` value on the fly using "evaluate and log". 
Check full [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58648315/3248922)
[image]