# How to change a value while debugging to a variable using a conditional breakpoint in a IntelliJ Kotlin project on the fly?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin, breakpoints

In an Java Project this is possible while debugging by “mis”-using a conditional breakpoint to set a value to a property or variable:

[Java Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4JL2.png)

Unfortunately the same thing is not possible in a Kotlin Project. The error is: Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context:

[Kotlin Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMLoE.png)

I know that I can do it in debugger window using “Set Value”, but then i have to do it every time manually. Using a conditional breakpoint/watchpoint the value is set automatically without even suspending the program until I delete the breakpoint. This is pretty useful for smoke test or presentations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Do not do that in the condition field, use "evaluate and log" - this breakpoint action is created specifically for this.

Also you can unset "suspend" and it will silently set value for you:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could execute a function to set the value:

```java
run { text = "Some Value" }
```

This is an expression; it returns Unit, but has the side effect of setting your variable.

If the condition field needs you to return a boolean you can add it after:

```java
run { text = "Some Value"; false }
```

This returns false so the execution wouldn't stop.

Comment: I thought about the same solution and tried it. It executes but sadly it does not change the value.

Comment: That's a bummer. It works for the evaluate expression panel. But I'm not exactly sure how this would be possible then.